# Boot screen is not going ahead after displaying black screen showing /dev/sda1:

Tags: boot, grub2, gnome

In order to speed up my computer, I mistakenly uninstalled gnome-shell and also killed gnome-shell through terminal, and after that Boot screen is not going ahead after displaying black screen showing  **/dev/sdb1: clean ----- blocks** and **/dev/sdb2: clean------blocks**

Could you please help me here, also internet is not available on that computer.

Many thanks

Comment: Time for a reinstall would be my suggestion.

Comment: Since that system is not connected to internet.. You have to download the gnome-shell package in other pc and then install in the effected pc. https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline